# python django не могу вывести список фотографий в виде таблицы типа как в instagram у меня все фотографии идут сплошной линией

Tags: html

[image: ВОТ КАК ИДУТ ФОТО]

```
<table width="500px">
            <thead>
                {% for key, value in decodesss.items %}
                    <th><img class="photos" src="data:image/png;base64, {{ value|slice:'2:-1' }} "width="255" height="255"></th>
                {% endfor %}
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Comment: Во-первых, th — это ячейка в строке таблицы, а вы даже не создали строку в таблице и этот html-код некорректный. Во-вторых, использовать таблицы для штук, которые не являются таблицами, в 2023 году — дурной тон